# Javascript - How to call variables from outside of one function

Tags: javascript

I have in my file `index.Js` :

```
const toto = ({tokenMode = false}) => {
const bPrice = usePriceB();
const aPrice = usePriceA();

return (
        <SectionWrapper
            section={{
                title: tokenMode ? 'Pools' : 'Farming',
                id: tokenMode ? 'pools' : 'farming',
                cards: generateCards().slice(0, 3),
            }}
        >
            <Card cards={generateCards().slice(0, 3)} ethereum={window.ethereum}/>
        </SectionWrapper>
    );
}
export default toto;
```

How to call variable aPrice and bPrice in other file .js ?

Edit : I just added my return of this function

Comment: You need to return `aPrice` and `bPrice`... otherwise, you can't. They're function variables.

Answer (score 0):

might need more info about intended use, but based on the info provided I'd guess you can do

```js
const toto = ({tokenMode = false}) => {
  const bPrice = usePriceB();
  const aPrice = usePriceA();
  return {aPrice, bPrice};
}
export default toto;
```

this will return the variables as an object that you can then get the values from

you could then use...

```js
const toto = require('./toto.js');
const tamto = toto();
console.log(tamto.aPrice);
console.log(tamto.bPrice);
```

---

### Update

In the context of a react app , you could use `useState`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const getters = {
  aPrice:null,
  bPrice:null
}

const setters = {
  aPrice:null,
  bPrice:null
}

export const Toto = () => {
  [getters.aPrice , setters.aPrice] = useState(null);
  [getters.bPrice , setters.bPrice] = useState(null);

  // runs once
  useEffect(() => {
    setters.aPrice(usePriceA());
    setters.bPrice(usePriceB());
  }, []);

  return (
    <SectionWrapper>
      ...
    </SectionWrapper>
  )
}
```

Then you can have the `getters` and `Toto` available

```js
import {Toto, getters} from `index.js`
//...
console.log(getters.aPrice);
```

Comment: sorry I forgot my return... I just added in the initial post. How can I do if I have already a return ?

Comment: oh, you're using it in a front-end library, that changes some things. In that case, you could use the library-specific store. If this is a react functional component, that you could use a hook `useState`

Comment: are the `aPrice` and `bPrice` global, or component specific?

Comment: I wouldike to be global yes

Comment: updated with `useState` and `useEffect`. Not sure how you set the values, but you might want to do it in `useEffect` with `[]` as second parameter, to only execute the first time

Comment: oh thank you for your feedback ! Actually I have an error. Const delcarations require an initialization value (the function toto())

Comment: ooops, fixed `export const Toto = () => {`

Comment: ...but I would like to point out, that while this may get you closer to the desired result, you may want to consider the app as a whole and how you are passing or storing data. For example, if you want this data be truly global and you may have multiple instances, this may not be the best solution. There are more elegant solutions that use `createContext` such as... [link1](https://dev.to/ryanmoragas/global-state-in-react-2kcp) [link2](https://labs.thisdot.co/blog/creating-a-global-state-with-react-hooks)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231964/discussion-between-devbsc-and-daniel).